# How to Disable any MD5 or 96-bit HMAC algorithms within the SSH configuration

Tags: linux, ssh, security, encryption

I received a vulnerability for one of the serverstoday as below:

> Disable any MD5 or 96-bit HMAC algorithms within the SSH configuration

How can I check if these algorithms are present in other servers and mitigate this vulnerability? How can I;

1. check for any matching algorithms that gives the above vulnerability
2. disable any MD5 algorithms
3. disable  96-bit HMAC algorithms

Can someone help me?

Comment: Post your SSHD configuration file for your OpenSSH server. You will want to update to the current stable version of OpenSSH if you are not already running it.